# i want use sshtunnel reconnect and query database with database of pythonanywhere

Tags: python, database, pythonanywhere, ssh-tunnel

```
import sshtunnel
import time
import logging
import mysql.connector
class SelectCommand():
    def __init__(self,dbcmd,value = None, mul = False):
        self.dbcmd = dbcmd
        self.value = value
        self.mul = mul

    def execute(self):
        try:
            print("try1")
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(
            user='**myuser**', password='**pass**',
            host='127.0.0.1', port=server.local_bind_port,
            database='**myuser$test**', autocommit = True
            )
            print("try2")
            connection.autocommit = True
            mycursor = connection.cursor()
            sql = self.dbcmd
            val = self.value
            mycursor.execute(sql, val)
            myresult = mycursor.fetchone()
            mycursor.close()
            connection.close()
            if myresult == None or self.mul == True:
                return myresult
            return myresult[0]
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return "server disconnect "



sshtunnel.SSH_TIMEOUT = 5.0
sshtunnel.TUNNEL_TIMEOUT = 5.0
def get_server():
    #sshtunnel.DEFAULT_LOGLEVEL = logging.DEBUG
    server = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
    ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
    ssh_username='**myuser**', ssh_password='**mypass**',
    remote_bind_address=('**myuser.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com**', 3306))
    return server

server = get_server()
server.start()

while True :
    if(server.is_active):
        print("alive... " + (time.ctime()))
        print(SelectCommand("SELECT * FROM A_table WHERE id = %s", (1,), mul = True).execute())
    else:
        print("reconnecting... " + time.ctime())
        server.stop()
        server = get_server()
        server.start()
    time.sleep(8)
```

[image]

Now i want use sshtunnel connect with database of pythonanywhere, and i want check connecting of sshtunnel if connect do select command else wait for new connecting. i try do [Python: Automatically reconnect ssh tunnel after remote server gone down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47531204/python-automatically-reconnect-ssh-tunnel-after-remote-server-gone-down) . but my problem is when i query database i try turn off my WIFI
my console show this message (Could not establish connection from **('127.0.0.1', 54466) to remote side of the tunnel)** and **Socket exception: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host (10054)** then it's result to stopping of my program. How can i fix.

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to turn off WIFI"? If you mean this literally, the connection is being closed by you.

Comment: yes. I want to reconnection but my program still work.

Comment: But what do you want to achieve? If you need your program to stop, you should kill/interrupt the process rather than turning off the wifi.

Comment: i want disconnect internet but program still loop for check re connection.